# PouchDB Error: Adapter is missing in node.js

Tags: node.js, pouchdb

I am creating db using memdown

```
new PouchDB("hello",{ "db" : require('memdown') } )
```

Returned db object:

```
{"__opts":{},"prefix":"_pouch_","_events":{},"taskqueue":
{"isReady":false,"failed":{"code":404},"queue":
[]},"_adapter":"leveldb","_db_name":"hello"}
```

Its failed in construction itself!

When I tried to perform destroy operation I got `Error: Adapter is missing

Versions :

```
 "memdown": "^1.1.2",

 "pouchdb": "^5.3.1"

  node : 5.9.1 /4.0.0
```